# Android text Partial colouring

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, string-formatting

```
    <string name="id">1. Tap <b><font fgcolor='#FF000000'>More</font></b> in the top-right corner.</string>
```

i want the "more" to be highlighted with BOLD and a different colour. Which works fine for light mode , but in night mode -> i want to be able to use a different colour. Whats the best way to do that ?

( I know about spannables , but the thing is... if i use a spannable text with indices , it will not out work with multiple languages )

Comment: Create two strings: One in the light mode strings XML with the color for light mode and one in the night mode strings XML with a different color. The text would be the same.

Comment: I did think of the same... but then , i am going to have a lot of string files that i need to maintain.

Comment: Why would you have a lot of string files? Because of a lot of languages?

Comment: yes. For now i have 10 languages , but i want to support a lot more

Comment: How many colors are you dealing with? Just two or could each language have two unique colors one for dark and one for light?

Comment: Just 2. One for light & another for dark , common to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These seem to be the requirements:

1. Support multiple languages.
2. Each language has at least one string that will have a color and bold applied to part of the string's text that is dependent upon whether the app is running in "night" or "light" mode.
3. "night" and "Light" mode will each use a single color that will differ from the other mode as defined in 2) above.
4. Use a minimum number of strings.

One way to do this is to define the colors as follows:

**colors.xml**

```
<color name="my_light_dark_color">#FFFF0000</color>
```

**colors.xml (night)**

```
<color name="my_light_dark_color">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

For "night" mode, "white" will be the color used. Otherwise, it will be "red".

Define the strings in the appropriate "string" resource files and mark the portion to which the color will be applied using *Annotation* spans. Below I use English and French for the example.

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="hello_string">Hello! How are <b><annotation color="my_light_dark_color">you</annotation></b>?</string>
```

**strings.xml (fr)**

```
<string name="hello_string">Bonjour! Comment allez-<b><annotation color="my_light_dark_color">vous</annotation></b>?</string>
```

Now that our resources are in place, we need a little code to splice it all together.

```
val textToColor = binding.textView.text.toSpannable()
val lightDarkColor =
        ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.my_light_dark_color, requireActivity().theme)

// Find all Annotation spans that specifies a color as a key with the right value.
textToColor.getSpans<android.text.Annotation>(0, textToColor.length)
    .filter { it.key == "color" && it.value == "my_light_dark_color"}.forEach {
        replaceSpan(textToColor, it, ForegroundColorSpan(lightDarkColor))
    }
binding.textView.text = textToColor

fun replaceSpan(spannable: Spannable, oldSpan: Any, newSpan: Any) {
    val spanStart = spannable.getSpanStart(oldSpan)
    val spanEnd = spannable.getSpanEnd(oldSpan)
    val flags = spannable.getSpanFlags(oldSpan)
    spannable.removeSpan(oldSpan)
    spannable.setSpan(newSpan, spanStart, spanEnd, flags)
}
```

The code above will require defining two values for the text color to be applied and one string for each language. The Annotation spans can be applied to each language as required.

For more information see

- [Styling With Annotations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithAnnotations)
- [Styling Android - AnnotationSpans – Part 1](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/annotationspans-part-1/)